# Using Hydrogen as a carrier gas for a GC; consideration of reactivity with analytes

Tags: hydrogen, chromatography, gas

In many cases people use H2 as a carrier gas for a GC. But does this exclude analysis of (say) systems with unsaturation or aromatic compounds etc. If a analysis uses a temperature program say up to 300 C (quite typical) doesn't the carrier gas H2 react with your analytes as this temperature?

Just wanting to know if there are specific guidelines about what sort of analytes H2 can be used as a carrier gas with. Or are the Temperatures / partial pressures too low to worry about internal reactions. As compared to other carrier gases e.g. N2 or Argon H2 would seem unusually reactive and hence I wonder.

Notwithstanding all the other advantages of H2 in terms of cost, viscosity etc. what about sheer reactivity?

Comment: Hydrogen, even at elevated temperatures, generally needs a catalytic surface to react with unsaturated systems